# No way to select OS

Tags: grub2

pls i am very new to ubuntu and after installing it from a wubi via a usb disk alongside windows 8  my system automatically still  boots windows 8, i then have to quickly press the esc key  go to boot manager and then Notebook hard drive before i can access grub and access ubuntu ...........

pls if anyone can help so i either get a grub on startup or the windows 8 blue screen selection choice menu like in the link ....... i sincerely have tried many options like typing a bunch of codes in terminal and the  (`sudo update-grub`) which keeps giving me an error message saying `unterminated quote d string`... ...............

[image]

ps: secure mode is disabled ...... any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the USB again into Ubuntu and follow the instructions below:

Open Terminal, and type:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX 
update-grub
exit && sudo umount /mnt/dev && sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts && sudo umount /mnt/proc && sudo umount /mnt/sys && sudo umount /mnt
```

Where `/dev/sdX` is your partition, like `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`.